# Permission Denied error when trying to run my app as a service with systemd

Tags: linux, permissions, systemd

I wanna run an app as a service by an unprivileged user in Ubuntu. Following is the command to create the user:

```
sudo groupadd -r mygroup
sudo useradd -r -s /bin/false -g mygroup myuser
sudo chown -R mygroup:myuser /path/to/my/app
```

Following is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Myapp server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/my/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/my/app/myapp.jar
User=myuser
Type=simple
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=120
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, when I start the service, I have the following error in the log:

```
Changing to the requested working directory failed: Permission denied
Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/java: Permission denied
```

I tried to add the user into sudo group with `sudo usermod -aG sudo myuser` and add sudo into ExecStart, doesn't work either.

```
Changing to the requested working directory failed: Permission denied
Failed at step CHDIR spawning sudo: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

The synopsis of chown is the following:

```
chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE...
```

You are giving it mygroup:myuser as arguments which is the wrong way around. Use:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:mygroup /path/to/my/app
```